# Java JAR: Writing to a file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Currently, in my eclipse project, I have a file that I write to. However, I have exported my project to a JAR file and writing to that directory no longer works. I know I need to treat this file as a classpath resource, but how do I do this with a BufferedWriter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have to treat it as a classpath resource to write to a file.  You would only have to do that if the file was in your JAR file, but you don't want to write to a file contained within your JAR file do you?

You should still be able to create and write to a file but it will probably be relative to the working directory - the directory you execute your JAR file from  (unless you use an absolute path).  In eclipse, configure the working directory from within the run configuration dialog.

Comment: True, bad wording.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably working in Linux. Because, in Linux, when you start your application from a JAR, the working directory is set to your home folder (/home/yourname/). When you start it from Eclipse, the working directory is set to the project folder.

To make sure you really know the files you are using are located in the project folder, or the folder where your JAR is in, you can use this piece of code to know where the JAR is located, then use the `File(File parent, String name)` constructor to create your files:

```
// Find out where the JAR is:
String path = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
// Create the project-folder-file:
File root = new File(path);
```

And, from now on, you can create all your File's like this:

```
File myFile = new File(root, "config.xml");
```

Of course, `root` has to be in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Such resources (when altered) are best stored in a sub-directory of `user.home`.  It is a reproducible path that the user should have write access to.  You might use the package name of the main class as a basis for the sub-directory.  E.G.

```
our.com.Main -> ${user.home}/our/com/
```

Comment: Much better to write to the current directory.  I hate these *nix oriented programs that assume they can and should write all sorts of crap to my home directory where ever and how ever they wish.

Comment: @Software Monkey What do you suggest instead?  `user.dir` is not stable, & the location-on-disk of the class/Jar files is not available to *any* JWS app. or applet.